# Python socket.error is not found (AttributeError: type object 'socket' has no attribute 'error')

Tags: python, sockets

I have this function and I don't know what's wrong:

```
def createSocket():
    try:
        global host , port ,socket
        host = ''
        port = 9999
        socket = socket.socket()
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("socket creation error: " + str(msg))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'socket' has no attribute 'error'
```

Comment: don't call your socket `socket`, it masks the module called `socket`

Comment: agreed -- change the variable name to `sock` and the problem will disappear

Comment: it worked , thanks !